# How to remove a specific element from a python list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I want to remove an A element using a B array of IDs, given the specific scalar ID 'C'

In matlab I can do this:

```
A(B == C) = []
```

This is an example of my code:

```
 boxes = [[1,2,20,20],[4,8,20,20],[8,10,40,40]]
 boxIDs = [1,2,3]


IDx = 2
```

I want to delete the second box completely out of the list.

How can I do this in python? I have numpy.

Comment: `A[B == C] = []`. Are you using 1d array, what is size/shape of your `A` and `B`?

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. It always deletes the first element?

Comment: Could you attach [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Without example data and your expecting output it's hard to answer your question.

Comment: I'm using a 4xm array of [x y w h] boxes, I have a corresponding array of boxIDs and need to delete a specific box according to a variable 'IDx'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use numpy indexing for that. You could find more information in the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html). For your case:

```
import numpy as np
boxes = np.array([[1,2,20,20],[4,8,20,20],[8,10,40,40]])
boxIDs = np.array([1,2,3])

IDx = 2

In [98]: boxes[boxIDs != IDx, :]
Out[98]:
array([[ 1,  2, 20, 20],
       [ 8, 10, 40, 40]])
```

Answer (score 2):

without import `numpy` you can `pop` out the element. try:

```
boxes = [[1,2,20,20],[4,8,20,20],[8,10,40,40]]
IDx = 1
pop_element = boxes.pop(IDx)
```

the list `boxes` now is `[[1, 2, 20, 20], [8, 10, 40, 40]]` and `pop_element` is `[4, 8, 20, 20]`

PS: in python indexes start from `0` instead of `1`.

Answer (score 0):

In plain-old-Python, I think you want to do this:

```
try:
    helpindex = boxIDs.index(IDx)
    del boxes[index], boxIDs[index]
except ValueError:
    # Already deleted
    pass
```

Note that if you are relying on `boxIDs` to be "parallel" with `boxes`, you have to make sure you keep them parallel by deleting from both.